# are views that query from other views also refreshed automatically

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

Let's say I have a view that queries from another view:

```
create view another_view as (select * from my_table);

create view one_view as (select * from another_view);

select * from one_view;
```

When I issue the last statement `select * from one_view;` does that also refreshes and queries `another_view` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are not persisted anywhere so they cannot be "refreshed". When you query from a view then the SQL engine will rewrite the query to use the view's query  and select directly from the underlying table(s) applying all the joins, filters, etc. from the view.

---

Given the setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (value) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

create view another_view as (select * from my_table);

create view one_view as (select * from another_view);
```

Then you can look at the explain plan for selecting from the view:

```sql
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select * from one_view;
```

Then:

```
SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

Which outputs:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 3804444429
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |          |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_TABLE |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Oracle does not select from any view, it rewrites the query to select directly from the underlying table. Therefore there is no concept of the view having to "refresh"; it is always whatever is current in the table.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PRY11RZ-)